# How to verify param is actually Json, not just a string

Tags: java, jackson, spring-validator

I have a JsonNode that I am accepting as a param to an endpoint. Looks something like this:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "data", example = "{}", required = true)
@NotNull(message = "data cannot be null")
protected JsonNode data;
```

I want to create a Validator called `@ValidJson`. The JsonNode itself will make sure that the information being fed to it is valid json, so if I pass something like:

`{"data" = "hello",}`, where there is an extra comma after the `"hello"`, it will throw an error. But how do I make sure I'm not getting something like `"Hello"` for JsonNode, which is valid json since a normal String is a valid json representation?

I was thinking at first of checking if the String is just alphanumeric and if it is, then I would consider it invalid, but then obviously someone can just pass a string with a symbol in it and it would be fine. The best solution I could think of was to check that the first and last characters are `{` and `}` respectively, and JsonNode would take care of the rest. But I don't know enough about `JsonNode`, so maybe someone here has a better idea?

Edit:

To be more specific with what I want, here are a couple of examples:

JsonNode will take care of incorrect Json. I want to do some stricter verification on the data I get in. I don't want to receive any *sort* of Json, I want the "real", serializable json that we all mean when we say json. If a user passes a string that looks like:

`"Hello"`
`"Hello world"`
`"I'm just a random String that isn't in a key:value structure"`

Etc, I want to throw an error and ask them for Json formatted in key:value structure like:

```
{
   "key": "value"
}
```

I was thinking of checking to see if the first and last string values are `{` and `}` respecitvely, as I mentioned in my comments, but I think that's too "hacky" and there could perhaps be a better method.

Comment: json as a query param seems rather off..

Comment: What do you mean? You have to send data to a post somehow... pretty standard to have json?

Comment: It should throw an error anyway since that's not valid JSON. But if you want to only allow a JSON *object* why would you define it as a generic node?

Comment: `JsonNode` has [`isObject()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#isObject()), as well as other validation methods such as `isArray()`, `isNumeric()` and `isTextual()`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @DaveNewton What isn't validjson? A normal string? It actually is

Comment: @VinceEmigh isObject looks prominsing...

Comment: @JohnLexus you said `as a param`... I assumed you were talking about a query param, but now I'm assuming you're talking about the request body....If that's the case, you should create a class that represents that json, and spring will handle the conversion (and spring will also throw errors if it's invalid)

Comment: @JohnLexus also `"hello"` is not valid json... see http://json.org/

Comment: @JohnLexus The example you show isn't valid JSON: there's an equal sign where there should be a colon.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't see an equal sign anywhere.

Comment: Oh, you mean in the one where I specifically make it invalid, yeah its meant to be there

Comment: @RobOhRob For your information.. 1. Spring doesn't handle the conversion, it's Jackson. 2. "Hello" is a perfectly fine JSON. It actually is not a Json **Object** but it's JSON.

Comment: @JohnLexus I see. I guess I was confused because you explicitly said it was the comma that made it invalid.

Comment: JSON.. JavaScript Object Notation...

Comment: @VinceEmigh Got back to this story a little while ago and while looking at the docs, found the solution and remembered that was what you suggested. You were completely right, gave you credit in my post. Thank you man

Comment: No problem. Just make sure to check out the JavaDocs (or in some cases, the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) when your issue doesn't involve any specific reference types) anytime you have an issue. Not only may you get a solution quicker, but you may also get exposed to some deeper insight that'll be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @VinceEmigh pointed out in the comments, `isObject` is the function I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson is designed to convert JSON into Java Objects. Although your usecase could work, it is most likely not very helpful. Take a look into https://www.baeldung.com/jackson this tutorial may help you to understand Jackson and its JSON conversion.

If you really want to use a JsonNode, Jackson would already check if it's a proper JSON, otherwise it would immediately throw an Exception because it can't parse it into a JsonNode.

If you want a **JSON Object** you could simply use a `Map<String, Object>` instead of **JsonNode**. This will handle the key-value part.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I check its _actual_ Json and not, say, just a string? If you pass "Hello" to JsonNode, it will work fine.

Comment: "Hello" is an absolutely correct JSON string. Due to that I really recommend you to take a look at the tutorial to find out how Jackson really works and how you can expect the JSON you are really expecting. See https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Suggest anything in particular? Seems like you know something I don't. Is it possible you could share it?

Comment: If you would tell us which data you are trying to get by your client, I'll be happy to help you. But if you don't provide us any more information, I can't help you. Probably the best way would be if you show us your expected Json

Comment: I added an edit, elt me know if that makes things clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. But my actual question was If you are looking for specific JSON data. e.g { "name": "test", "country": "France" }?

Comment: Ahh.... sorry, no, I am not looking for specific Json data. I am only looking for json data that is in key:value pair. That's it. It could be anything as long as it is valid (which JsonNode will take care of) and in key:value pair.

Comment: Meaning my check won't be anything like asserting that a json node `data.equalTo({"name": "test", "country":"france"})`, but more like is {"name":"test"...} a json in "key:value" pair. So "hello" is not in that format so it's incorrect.